# Nginx - set cookie from one url to another for different users

Tags: nginx, cookies, lua, nginx-config, openresty

I'm trying to set up hortonworks schema-registry with openresty.

we have google oauth enabled for our schema-registry ui. The google oauth passes a cookie called "_token" to ***/ui*** and all other subsequent paths except ***/api***

This is because we may want to hit ***/api*** directly as well. (without google authentication).

The problem is since ***/api*** is exluded from the list, I'm unable to pass the cookie "_token" to any of the requests under ***/api***

In my access_by_lua , there is a condition where I check for the cookie,

if the cookie is present - the user is authenticated and then he can move ahead
if not - we do some other checks to validate the request, and pass it ahead accordingly or return an error statement

My question is, if I want to pass the cookie from ***/ui*** to ***/api***, how do I go ahead with it?

Also , the cookie should be set only for that particular user so that my other apps can communicate quickly.

What I've tried till now:

I tried setting a global cookie _token after reading it from the ***/ui*** path. 
This doesnt seem to work since it sets the cookie for all requests (even the ones coming from apps) and the value of the cookie is static based on the first _token it receives from ***/ui***